# How to specify viewmodel parameter in MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo

Tags: android, xamarin, android-viewpager, mvvmcross

I want to build a custom viewpager adapter to manipulate the viewpager fragments. Instead of loading viewpager by navigating a list of viewmodels, I will have to manipulate (add & remove) MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo in the adapter. Before working on the adapter code, I am stuck in passing parameter to viewmodel with MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo.

Prior to Mvvmcross 7, MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo can be built using syntax

```
MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo(string title, string tag, Type fragmentType, Type viewModelType, object parameterValuesObject = null).
```

Parameter can be passed easily with this syntax.

From 7.x, it became

```
MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo(string title, string tag, Type fragmentType, MvxViewModelRequest request)
```

where

```
MvxViewModelRequest(Type viewModelType, IMvxBundle parameterBundle, IMvxBundle presentationBundle)
```

that I can no longer pass parameter.

I tried the following code to specify parameter in the MvxViewModelRequest but not successful:

```
IMvxJsonConverter mvxJsonConverter = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxJsonConverter>();
Core.Models.AppSetting appSetting = new Core.Models.AppSetting() { Id = 1 };
IMvxBundle mvxParmBundle = new MvxBundle(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "parameter", mvxJsonConverter.SerializeObject(appSetting) } });
var fragments = new List<MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo>
{
    new MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo("1", "", typeof(Tab1View), new MvxViewModelRequest(typeof(Tab1ViewModel), mvxParmBundle, null)),
    new MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo("2", "", typeof(Tab2View), new MvxViewModelRequest(typeof(Tab2ViewModel))),
    new MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo("3", "", typeof(Tab3View), new MvxViewModelRequest(typeof(Tab3ViewModel)))
};
viewPager.Adapter = new MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter(Activity, ChildFragmentManager, fragments);
```

When Tab1ViewModel is loaded, the Prepare function is not fired. What is the correct syntax or right way to specify the viewmodel parameter in MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo?

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: Does Init fire if you create such method?

Comment: @Cheesebaron I added Init. It was fired without value. Thanks to your hint, I found the ancient method InitFromBundle works. I will use that to continue the test of viewpager adapter. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue and @Cheesebaron helped me!
So this function:

`MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo(string title, string tag, Type fragmentType, MvxViewModelRequest request)`

Can also be used like this:

`MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo(string title, string tag, Type fragmentType, MvxViewModelInstanceRequest request)`

because MvxViewModelInstanceRequest is of type MvxViewModelRequest. Inside the MvxViewModelInstanceRequest, you can just pass in your ViewModel instance populated.

---

So this line:

`new MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo("1", "", typeof(Tab1View), new MvxViewModelRequest(typeof(Tab1ViewModel), mvxParmBundle, null)),`

can just be

`new MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo("1", "", typeof(Tab1View), new MvxViewModelInstanceRequest(new Tab1ViewModel())),`

so you can pass any parameters in the constructor.